# How do I run Space 1889/Twilight 2000/Mega Traveller in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, backwards-compatibility, space-1889, twilight-2000

I have windows 7. I have two old Paragon games Space 1889 and Twilight 2000. How do I play them or get them to work in windows 7? I have just obtained the three Mega Traveller games and want to play them also.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to Mega Traveller, I can say from personal experience that they work just fine with [Dosbox](http://www.dosbox.com/). If the other two games are from the same era, they probably will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

For old DOS games, you use a program called [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/), which emulates a DOS-driven machine. Install the program, mount a directory where you'll keep your old games as drive C: (never mount your HD directly), mount the game's install disc as D:, install and play.